# Audio not included in rendered file

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, audio

I'm using the "Video Editing" feature and have created a rough cut of my project in a new Sequence.

I have included other Sequences there, and put an audio track on top of it. When I play it back in blender it works fine and the audio is playing. When I render it, there is no audio.

[image]

I've enabled audio in my Output section, for both, the scene with my 3d objects (although that scene doesn't contain any audio, but I wasn't sure if that was necessary) and the scene in which I'm doing the video editing:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I opened the MPEG-4 in VLC to see whether it might just be a compatibility problem and VLC played the file with audio! So it appeared to be a container or audio codec compatibility problem with Quicktime and Apple preview.

Switching the audio codec from MP3 to AAC worked.